# weird slash appears in html

Tags: php, html, markup, slash

As i do some html markup thru php output:

```
echo '<h2>Events Calendar</h2><table border="2" width="100%"><th>';
...
```

a **weird slach** appears in this way (under *Events Calendar* and above the html table markup):
[image]

As i look in debugger i find no hint where it's from...
The table markup is ok, all tags are paired.
What's the cause might be?

Comment: Most likely it is outside your proper table markup, like /<tr>

Comment: Does your CSS have something like `:before` ? maybe it is adding it via css? A left over typo.

Comment: @mplungjan - true. I've fixed it. You might form it as answer and i'll check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it is outside your proper table markup, like `/<tr>`

Anything between the tags in a table is normally rendered before the table.